# Converting string to time in PHP in this example

Tags: php

I have a string for a date and a string for a time. I need to convert them to the format `Y-m-d h:i`

This is what I have so far. I am converting the date string to date format:

```
$fechasolucion = $_POST['fecha'];
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($fechasolucion));
```

Now I need to include the string `$hora (19:29)` to the time part of the given date.

I need to get at the end this output:

```
$fecha = "2017-07-01"
$hora = "19:29"

$date = "2017-07-01 19:29"
```

Comment: Concatenate the variables, and try it

Comment: $date = $fecha.' '.$hora;

Comment: All you need to do is concatenate the 2 unless you mean you want a different output date format???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatinate the two variables `$fecha` and `$hora` and then convert it to time.

```
<?php
    $fecha = "2017-07-01";
    $hora = "19:29";

    $date_string = $fecha . ' ' . $hora;
    $time = strtotime( $date_string );

    echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i', $time );
?>
```

**Output:**

```
2017-07-01 19:29
```